# use gmail API token on localhost and hosting at the same time

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I want to use Gmail API in my hosting, but every time the token is updated in my localhost, the application published in the hosting cannot consume the API.

What is the configuration I need? I want to work with the API in my localhost without affecting the hosting application.

este es el json con los datos de acceso:

{"installed":{"client_id":"123456-abcd123abcd.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"applied-summer-xxxxx","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"xxxxxxx","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost","http://example.com/"]}}

Answer (score 2):

Set up different API credentials for each instance type. One for testing locally and one for production hosting environment.